# How to create a pluginable Java program?

Tags: java, plugins, plugin-architecture

I want to create a Java program that can be extended with plugins. How can I do that and where should I look for?

I have a set of interfaces that the plugin must implement, and it should be in a jar. The program should watch for new jars in a relative (to the program) folder and registered them somehow.

---

Although I do like Eclipse RCP, I think it's too much for my simple needs.

Same thing goes for Spring, but since I was going to look at it anyway, I might as well try it.

But still, I'd prefer to find a way to create my own plugin "framework" as simple as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to build a Plugin system with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465099/best-way-to-build-a-plugin-system-with-java). This is earlier, but the other became more popular in the end.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I've done this for software I've written in the past, it's very handy. I did it by first creating an Interface that all my 'plugin' classes needed to implement. I then used the Java [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to load those classes and create instances of them.

One way you can go about it is this:

```
File dir = new File("put path to classes you want to load here");
URL loadPath = dir.toURI().toURL();
URL[] classUrl = new URL[]{loadPath};

ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classUrl);

Class loadedClass = cl.loadClass("classname"); // must be in package.class name format
```

That has loaded the class, now you need to create an instance of it, assuming the interface name is MyModule:

```
MyModule modInstance = (MyModule)loadedClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: I know I'm a little late on this thread, but what if you wanted to loop through all given classes in a directory and load them? is there somewhere I can see a working implementation and code online? Other than that, I understand most of you code and its very simple, thanks! +1

Comment: @CodyRichardson There is a complete example of simple implementation at http://www.knowbase.org/viewtopic.php?id=31 ; it makes use of Java 8 and Gradle 4.

Comment: @Alexiy Thanks for that link, it helped a lot and is basically everything I needed. It was a little complicated at first (mostly the lambdas) but that's just because I'm a java noob :) I looked it over a few times and it made a lot more sense. Thanks for that!

Comment: My link above doesn't exist anymore, the tutorial is now hosted here - https://alexiyorlov.github.io/tutorials/java-plugins.html

Comment: I tried this variant and many more. But what happens is this: I cannot cast my class to an interface, because this throws a ClassCastException. Is there a problem with Java 1.8 or bigger?

Answer (score 18):

Look into [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org).

On one hand, OSGi provides all sorts of infrastructure for managing, starting, and doing lots of other things with modular software components.  On the other hand, it could be too heavy-weight for your needs.

Incidentally, Eclipse uses OSGi to manage its plugins.

Comment: +1 for OSGi. I find it the right size between simple ClassLoader trickeries (which will leave you a lot of wheels to reinvent) and Eclipse RCP (big framework for not so complex task).

Answer (score 16):

I recommend that you take a close look at [the Java Service Provider (SPI) API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html).  It provides a simple system for finding all of the classes in all Jars on the classpath that expose themselves as implementing a particular service.  I've used it in the past with plugin systems with great success.

Comment: Note that the sun.misc.Service class has been superseded by the class java.util.ServiceLoader.

Answer (score 6):

Although I'll second the accepted solution, if a basic plugin support is needed (which is the case most of the time), there is also the [Java Plugin Framework](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/) (JPF) which, though lacking proper documentation, is a very neat plugin framework implementation.

It's easily deployable and - when you get through the classloading idiosynchrasies - very easy to develop with. A comment to the above is to be aware that plugin loadpaths below the plugin directory must be named after the *full* classpath in addition to having its class files deployed in a normal package path named path. E.g.

```
plugins
`-com.my.package.plugins
  `-com
    `-my
      `-package
        `-plugins
          |- Class1.class
          `- Class2.class
```

Answer (score 4):

At the home-grown classloader approach: 
While its definitely a good way to learn about classloaders there is something called "classloader hell", mostly known by people who wrestled with it when it comes to use in bigger projects. Conflicting classes are easy to introduce and hard to solve.

And there is a good reason why eclipse made the move to OSGi years ago.
So, if its more then a pet project, take a serious look into OSGi. Its worth looking at.
You'll learn about classloaders PLUS an emerging technolgy standard.

Comment: osgi is nice but for small plugins that are loaded at boot and then untouched it's too large and complex

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered building on top of Eclipse's Rich Client Platform, and then exposing the Eclipse extension framework?

Also, depending on your needs, the Spring Framework might help with that and other things you might want to do:  http://www.springframework.org/