# Java Web application "plugin" architecture

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, plugins, architecture

Please give an advise on how to do "plugin" architecture for Java web application.

Currently we are using quite simple and standard Spring+Hibernate+Struts 2 in Tomcat servlet container. (Built with maven)

I need something like [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). Where any module can be enabled/disabled, updated
[image: Redmine UI]

Please exclude heavy options like OSGi, Portlet.

- OSGi is too heavy, there is no good adoption of the technology for web. I already looked at [Eclipse Germini](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/);
- [Portlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification) it just old, and never was popular.

Comment: I have awarded bounty, but question is still note closed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will try to provide several possible solution. I did spent some time preparing small PoCs for the project I'm working on, so let's hope the options below are relevant.

Important note: it is really easy to define some extension point, do resolve and find available implementations. There are a lot of solutions available, for example good and simple one -- [JSPF](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/)

**Resources are the main problem for WEB applications**

**OSGi**

OSGi, is not that bad and can be useful. It seems to be heavy (and some implementations are heavy) but this is price of standardized platform. I would suggest to check [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/). It can be used in a "lightweight" mode. By the way, it includes Web Console which is build as loosely coupled plugin-based application, could be helpful:

[image]

Some examples [Extending the Apache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console/extending-the-apache-felix-web-console.html)

> The Web Console can be extended by registering an OSGi service for the
>   interface javax.servlet.Servlet with the service property
>   felix.webconsole.label set to the label (last segment in the URL) of
>   the page. The respective service is called a Web Console Plugin or a
>   plugin for short.

You can also check [eie-manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eie/) which is clean and simple and uses OSGi to manage plugins. Could be a good example for you.

**Custom plugin framework**

I would suggest to review solution behind [Jenkins/Hudson](http://jenkins-ci.org/). I would say Jenkins plug-in system is quite mature and reliable. Can be used as a good example.

[image]

Please also check [Hudson Plugin Architecture](http://hudson-ci.org/docs/HudsonArch-Plugin.pdf)

**Simple solution**

For my project I've build plugin abstraction layer based on [JSPF](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/) with custom dependency resolver.

PROS:

- simple and small
- clean concept
- works good

CONS:

- without proper plugin management can be slow (full classpath search)
- provides very basic functionality
- may require additional attention

I would suggest to use [JSPF](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/) only if you really need some simplicity and want to control everything. [JPF](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/) provides a lot of interesting features out of the box, for example:

> Plug-ins can be "hot-registered" and even de-registered during
>   application execution. What's more, registered plug-ins can be
>   activated and deactivated "on the fly", minimizing runtime resource
>   usage.

The problem is JPF is dead.

**Suggestion**

Do spend some time with [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/). It is mature enough, so your time investments may pay back a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the answers to this question: [Best way to build a Plugin system with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465099/best-way-to-build-a-plugin-system-with-java)

If you don't trust the plugin code, you can implement sandboxing, as described here: [Sandbox against malicious code in a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application)

The open-source [Java Plug-in Framework](http://jpf.sourceforge.net)  project supports plugin deactivation, you can get inspired from it even if it is too heavy for your purposes.

Comment: How to apply this to web parts? Would you make all plugins as .war?

Comment: Well, if these plugins can be independent webapps, then you don't have to do anything, for example the Tomcat manager webapp allows you to start/stop/reload the webapps without having to shut down and restart the server: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: plugins should not be independent webapps. In this way there will be a lot work of how to integrate them (cross links, security, simgle sign-on etc)

Comment: Then I guess it makes no sense to make the plugins as .war files.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian open sourced their plugin system [here](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-plugins). I see it is being worked heavily by Atlassian team. Worth to explore its [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Plugin+Framework)