# How start a web plugin based project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, plugins, jenkins

I will start a new web project (Java) and before start I want analyze some code for web applications that could be extended using plugins on an easy way.

I have some experience with Jenkins/Hundson CI web application and I like the plugin system that this application have. I don't know if Jenkins/hudson uses a "standard" framework or a custom one for plugin management and deployment.

My objectives are:

1. Simple to extends. I will have "widgets" (pieces of the page) with some tables/graphs from a common repository (possibly a database). If I need a new grid/report/form, then I only need a new plugin that cover this functionality.
2. Easy to update. A central repository with all the plugins developed. A new version available, intermediately it can be updated on all the installed instances.

Any suggestion?.

I have check the jenkins repository but it's really extends and appear that the web core use a different one  : https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched about plugins and finally i'm agree with the comments in : [Java Web application "plugin" architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354466/java-web-application-plugin-architecture)

Depends of the complexity of the application you can create your own solution or use a more complex solution like OSGI.