# Creating a Login/Update Client for Application Java

Tags: java, sockets

I've been looking into trying to create a Client that a user will login to, then 
 the login client will check the version of the program and either download the new update or continue with opening the main application.

The issue that I'm currently facing is that I would like to have the 'main application' separate from the Login/Update client and not directly executable for the user.  I have been reading about ClassLoader. However I'm unsure if this is how it is done.

I have the basic Socket/GUI ready but I am stuck on the separate application that is only opened from the login client.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd say take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465099/best-way-to-build-a-plugin-system-with-java If you build your main application as plugin to Login/update client, it should prevent you from running it on its own. Also it will allow you an easy reuse of client for different applications.

Comment: I'm looking into this now. Thanks.