# How to add a plugin-architecture in my Java application?

Tags: java, design-patterns, plugins, plugin-architecture

I have a Java  command-line-application, which creates a report file after running some steps defined in the source-code.
Now I want to separate those steps from the core functionality of my application, because I want that the 
application can run dynamically loaded "steps".
This means, the core functionality of my application is to create the report file. And the separated "steps" should provide the content of the report.

I decided to realize those steps as plug-ins in my application. Everyone, who uses 
the application can extend it with already existing or own written plug-ins.

Now my question is, what is the best way - in my case - to develop a plug-in system for my application? I researched a lot and got
to much input. I can't decide how should I resolve the problem.

Interesting question from SO:

- [Best way to build a Plugin system with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465099/best-way-to-build-a-plugin-system-with-java)
- [How to create a pluginable Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449/how-to-create-a-pluginable-java-program)

During my research I collected some informations how i could resolve it:

- Using ServiceLoader: a simple service-provider loading facility.
- Using org.openide.util.Lookup from NetBeans(dynamic registration and lookup of components)
- Defining a own Plug-in interface, which must be implemented from the plug-ins. And then using the Java ClassLoader to 
  load those classes and create instances of them.
- Using OSGi, but I think it is to "big" for my purpose.

What is the best way to solve my problem with:

- a elegant plug-in architecture (perhaps with use of some design patterns),
- easy to maintain source-code,
- and easy to develop plug-ins.

Is my approach with a plug-in system correct? Or is there something else what could i use?