# How is the Stage instantiated in this JavaFX sample code?

Tags: java, javafx

This is a simple JavaFX starting point.

DemoApp inherits from Application. Application has an abstract method and that needs to be implemented. That's the @Overriden one.

The thing that confuses me is the parameter of the method. It has a class type and a name. Right?

But how did the name "stage" get instantiated to create an object if there is no **= new Stage();**" ? It is only "Stage stage" and not "Stage stage = new Stage();"

```
public class DemoApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: When a JavaFX application is launched via `Application#launch` then a sequence of events occurs which is [documented here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) (under _Life-cycle_). The JavaFX runtime instantiates the specified application class via reflection and then invokes the life-cycle methods in the appropriate order at the appropriate time. What this means is that the `Stage` passed to `#start(Stage)` is created by the JavaFX runtime (i.e. by internal code) and then passed to the method when invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `class` is like a Java `class` and is executed by a [classloader](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders). The role of this classloaser is to execute the `start` function by [reflection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-java/), and other functions available in your `class` if needed.
In the case of JavaFX, `Stage` is already instantiated as a parameter and you use it to show the `Scene`. So you don't have to worry about it.
You can read about [template](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) design pattern and [IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449/how-to-create-a-pluginable-java-program), it will help you understand the principle behind.

Comment: It's not just "like a" java class, it is a java class. JavaFX is just a java api, so in most cases all of your JavaFX application is implemented in java. The fact that some library is involved does not change this fact.

Comment: @fabian Of course, I know. It just for the explanation I used the `like a java class` expression. I am trying to explain it in a general purpose.